# Reload TeamCity build configuration programatically

Tags: rest, teamcity

I am creating multiple TeamCity projects via the rest api.
After adding some Versioned Settings properties via:

```
teamcity/app/rest/projects/MyProject/projectFeatures
```

I would like to be able to reload the projects programmatically, so that the changes take effect.

I don't see anything in the rest api that can do that. Does anyone has any suggestion on how to do that?

Currently I am going to project configuration -> Versioned Settings -> Context Parameters, and I manually save the changes which triggers a reload of the configuration and applying the required settings.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there's no api method to reload versioned settings. However, you could try to select `use settings from VCS` option in Versioned Settings. It should force TeamCity to reload versioned settings on each build

[image]